# Flexbox Formatting Issue When Including Text and Image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create something that looks like this using Flexbox & I'm having difficulties. See image example:

[image]

I've tried doing this with floats and have decided that it's too challenging. So I'm playing with flexbox instead.

I'm also using my css to pass through the image.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container>div {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  width: 300px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.row_cell {
  flex: 1
}

.phoneimg {
  display: flex;
  background-image: url(%image(MS_HR_MR_PHONE_FL));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  content: "";
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
  background-size: 55px 90px;
  */ width: 55px;
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>
    <div class="phoneimg">
      <div>column1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="phoneimg">
      <div>column2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="phoneimg">
      <div>column3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="rowcell">row</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm expecting to see columns but everything stacks vertically.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with an hierarchical approach with flex. First use flex in column direction for two rows and then on the first row, you can use flex on the row direction just the way you did it.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <style>
    .parent-container {
      background-color: DodgerBlue;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .flex-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .flex-container>div {
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      width: 300px;
      justify-content: space-around;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 20px;
      font-size: 30px;
    }
    
    .row {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 20px;
      font-size: 30px;
    }
    
    .row_cell {
      flex: 1
    }
    
    .phoneimg {
      display: flex;
      background-image: url(%image(MS_HR_MR_PHONE_FL));
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      content: "";
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
      background-size: 55px 90px;
      */ width: 55px;
      height: 90px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parent-container">
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div>
        <div class="phoneimg">
          <div>column1</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="phoneimg">
          <div>column2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="phoneimg">
          <div>column3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="rowcell">row</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please explain your solution as just providing an answer will help future users

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style>
        .flex-container {
            display: flex; 
            justify-content: center;

        }

        .flex-container > div {
            border: 1px solid #fff;
            width: 300px;
/*
            justify-content: space-around;

            margin: 10px;
            padding: 20px;
            font-size: 30px;
*/
        }

        .row {   
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .row_cell {   
            flex: 1
        }

        .phoneimg {
            display: flex; 
            background-image: url(%image(MS_HR_MR_PHONE_FL));
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            content: "";
            background-color    : rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
            background-size: 55px 90px;*/
            width: 55px;
            height: 90px;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .phoneimg div
        {
            font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 15px;
        }
.fa
        {
                font-size: 45px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="flex-container">

        <div>

            <div class="phoneimg">
                <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                <div>1.800.xxx.xxxx<br>
1.555.xxx.xxxx</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="phoneimg">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                <div>Email US</div>
      </div>
        </div>
     <div>
        <div class="phoneimg"> 
            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
            <div>Address Line1<br>
            Address Line2<br>
            Address Line3</div> 
        </div>
        </div>
         </div>
<div class="row">
<div class="rowcell">Monday - Friday<br>
    8 A.M - 5.00 P.M<br>
    Excluding State Holidays</div> 
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: please explain your solution as just providing an answer will help future users